# How to set a reference in http-conf:proxyAuthorization Conduit (XML)

Tags: xml, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I have in my XML Conduit:

```
<http-conf:proxyAuthorization>
        <sec:UserName>${proxyUsername}</sec:UserName>
        <sec:Password>#{proxySetter.getPassword()}</sec:Password>
</http-conf:proxyAuthorization>
```

But I need to set a reference to the sec:Password sample. Anything I put into this field is basically used as the string literal for basic auth. How would I call a method to populate this ref? I cannot hard code the password anywhere for security reasons.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it deployed into JBoss FUSE(Karaf OSGi based) container? If so, you can use encrypted property placeholders for the sensitive password properties, please take a look at [1] to get more details. It support both spring-dm and blueprint configuration

[1]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Security_Guide/FMQSecurityEncryptProperties.html

Freeman